# unique_ptr::get() function with virtual and non-virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I am using VS2012.
I am porting code from raw pointer to unique_ptr and facing a problem.
Here I have tried to simulate the scenario:

```
class xyz{
  public:
    virtual int getm();
    int get();       
    static std::unique_ptr<xyz> returnbase();
};

class abc:public xyz
{
public:
    int getm() {return 0;}
};

std::unique_ptr<xyz> xyz::returnbase()
{
    std::unique_ptr<xyz> u_Swift(nullptr);
    u_Swift =  std::unique_ptr<xyz>(dynamic_cast<xyz*>(new abc()));
    return u_Swift;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    xyz* x1 = xyz::returnbase().get();
    x1->get();
    x1->getm();
    return 0;
}
```

I get a crash "Access Violation" while calling virtual function.
I am surprised why this is crashing for virtual functions?

Thru watch I can see that virtual pointer is corrupted after assignment. But why this is corrupted, I am curious about.

Comment: Why do you write such dramatically verbose code? For example, `returnbase()` should consist of a single statement: `return std::unique_ptr<xyz>(dynamic_cast<xyz*>(new xyz()));`

Comment: What sense is there in casting `new xyz()` to `xyz*`? It already is a `xyz*`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with virtual functions.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No: `return std::make_unique<xyz>();`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes yes, but I didn't want to change the semantics. Even with its own confused semantics, the structure of the original code is absurd.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What semantics did I change? The `dynamic_cast` is redundant by definition (`[expr.dynamic.cast]/3`).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're right -- the dynamic cast isn't dynamic at all.

Comment: @KerrekSb, my main intention was to know about unique_ptr crash so I tried to keep minimal code. Added derived class now to explain dynamic_cast in my problem.

Comment: @Nipun You never need to `dynamic_cast` to a base class either.

Comment: @molbdnilo: At least not to a *non-virtual* base!

Comment: @Nipun: Fine, but can you please make your code less ugly? Format it, get rid of all the `public` noise (use `struct` for example code), and remove the redundant statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `x1` is a dangling pointer, because the temporary unique pointer that owns its initial pointee is destroyed at the end of the first statement in `main`, and the pointee is destroyed as a consequence.

```
 xyz* x1 = xyz::returnbase().get();
 //        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^
 //         temporary object       ^-- destroyed here
```

To retain the object, you need to make it non-temporary, like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<xyz> thing = xyz::returnbase();
    xyz * x1 = thing.get();

    // ... use x1 and *x1 ...

}  // thing goes out of scope and *thing is destroyed
```